# Handling Microservice Failures in a Consul-Managed Architecture

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, api-gateway, consul

In my microservice-based architecture that utilizes Consul as a service registry, if one of the services registered in Consul fails its health check, will the API gateway redirect requests to that microservice?

So, I want to determine whether my API gateway is still sending requests to a microservice that has failed its health check.